# ClassNotFoundException exception after updating the minSdkversion to 21

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Started getting this error after updating the value of minSdkVersion to 21 from 19. It occurs only on 5.0 devices, devices with OS 6+ works fine

Application has all the multidex properties included. Also as suggested by google that multidex is not require if minSdkVersion is 21 but that too does throws the similar error.

Tried cleaning the project, cache etc

Tried disabling the instant run but no luck so far.

```
                            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/agent/android/instrumentation/GsonInstrumentation;
                                                                                 at com.demo.app.persistence.Datastore.getMember(Datastore.java:142)
                                                                                 at com.demo.app.Application.initDatastore(Application.java:139)
                                                                                 at com.demo.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:84)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5010)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.GsonInstrumentation" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.demo.apptracker-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.babycenter.pregnancytracker-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                 at com.demo.app.persistence.Datastore.getMember(Datastore.java:142) 
                                                                                 at com.demo.app.Application.initDatastore(Application.java:139) 
                                                                                 at com.demo.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:84) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5010) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.GsonInstrumentation
                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                        ... 15 more
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Could you please add you gradle.build?

Comment: clean project, change something (for example version code) then resync and build project.

Comment: @BhalchandraSW for security reasons I cannot able to upload my entire build.gradle file, but if you need to know anything specific than I can provide you.

Comment: Please post `com.newrelic.agent.android` group's dependency

Comment: @BhalchandraSW App level -  compile com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.10.0
Project level  - classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.10.0'

Comment: Try with latest version [5.14.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.newrelic.agent.android/agent-gradle-plugin/5.14.0)

Comment: hmmm I tried with 5.13.0 but no luck, will try with 5.14.0 but it doesn't seems related to new relic bz sometimes I get the logs for other classes like Application

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.demo.app.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.demo.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.demo.apptracker-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.babycenter.pregnancytracker-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib,

Comment: @EliasFazel no luck :(

Comment: Is it possible to post all dependencies?

Comment: @BhalchandraSW your guess is that it might be related to dependencies? Its weird that how-come its working for OS's 6 and 7. We are using many third party libraries and I cannot put all names here.